# ReportWebService.Schedule description date format

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, reporting-services

I'm querying reporting service Schedules and getting back the array of items. Within these items is a description field like this:

```
Every 1 hour(s) and 0 minute(s), starting 11/1/2014 at 2:00 AM and ending 3/31/2015
```

Are there any options to set the culture for this so it returns as a UK format? i.e.

```
Every 1 hour(s) and 0 minute(s), starting 1/11/2014 at 2:00 AM and ending 31/3/2015
```

My code is:

```
           var reportService = new ReportingService2005();
            reportService.Credentials = GetReportCredentials();

            var schedules = reportService.ListSchedules();
            var scheduleViews = schedules.Select(s => new ReportScheduleSearchView { 
                Guid = s.ScheduleID,
                Name = s.Name,
                Description = s.Description,
                State = s.State.ToString(),
            });
```

Comment: Where are these `11/1/2014` and `3/31/2015` comes from? Are they `string` or `DateTime` values? If they are strings, did you try to parse them first and then formatting? If they are DateTimes, did you try to formatting them? Or more important, did you try anything at all?

Comment: They are date time values from the schedule item. The description is automatically generated based on these values, but the values appear in the correct format  (31/03/2015)

Answer (score 0):

The language of the Report Manager is defined by the browser settings (in IE: Tools > Internet Options > Languages). Perhaps you could try [setting the locale/culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b28bx3bh(v=vs.110).aspx) of your application to [en-GB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh441729.aspx).

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Globalization;
// Set the culture
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
// Set the UI culture
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
```